# Internal Virtual Server

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

I've been reading about Virtuals servers with fortinet:
https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.2.0/cookbook/713497/virtual-server

But it seems that only works redirecting a public IP to internal IP's.

What I need to do is to point an internal (virtual) IP to a set of other internal IP's.

My situation is this:
I have 3 real servers:

- Server 1 Local IP: 192.168.1.10
- Server 2 Local IP: 192.168.1.11
- Server 3 external IP: 142.250.72.238

My local domain is mydomain.lan

My local DNS (bind9) must resolve to a virtual (local) IP:
mydomain.lan -> 10.10.10.1

When the client loads website at http://mydomain.lan
DNS server resolves IP to 10.10.10.1

Then the router should decide which real server must redirect the client to, on a certain defined order: Server 1 first, if it timeouts, Server 2, etc. Timeout should be defined at router level.

How is the proper way to do this using Fortinet (Fortigate)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only port forward each public-IP/port combination to a single private-IP/port combination. What you're looking for might be a *reverse proxy* (that you'd port forward to and then let it forward to the actual server) but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Which part is not clear?
Basically, what I need is that a local domain can be resolved dynamically to different IP's, based on availability. 

If the user enters "http://mydomain.lan" on the browser, it should be forwarded to an available server. If "server 1" is not available, the the domain should be redirected to "server 2", and so on. Is that even possible with Fortinet?